# Any way to see variables defined in PyCharm console with one liner?

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm if I use the Python Console to define some variable like:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> scale = np.random.rand(1)[0]
```

I am not getting any feedback, so to actually see the value of `scale` I need to:

```
>>> scale
0.6160226502566429
```

Any way of getting the value without the second line?

Comment: That's what the interactive session is supposed to do; an assignment statement isn't an expression in Python, it doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python3.8+, you can use `(scale := np.random.rand(1)[0])`, which will return the value but also assign the variable.

See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/